# iOS Simulator Stuck on Launch Page after Update to XCode 7

Tags: ios, swift2, xcode7

I updated to Xcode 7 from Xcode 6 and updated my code to swift 2.0 from swift 1.2. When I run the project, there are no compile time errors, just warnings, and the build is successful. The problem I am having is that the main.storyboard does not load. By this i mean all that is shown in the simulator is the launch page and the initial view controller is never put into the hierarchy (i believe). When i updated my code to swift 2.0, i manually updated the AppDelegate which i did not expect and is why i think there may be something wrong with the file. I also get a Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2 ...) error which i understand to be a recursion error but don't understand how to resolve the issue.

Things I have tried

Reinstalling Xcode 7

Using Simulator 8.4 instead of 9.0

Updated to last swift syntax (Edit->Convert->To Latest Swift Syntax)

Here is my AppDelegate File

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}

func applicationWillResignActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
    // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and throttle down OpenGL ES frame rates. Games should use this method to pause the game.
}

func applicationDidEnterBackground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
    // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
}

func applicationWillEnterForeground(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called as part of the transition from the background to the inactive state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) {
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
}

func applicationWillTerminate(application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
    self.saveContext()
}

// MARK: - Core Data stack

lazy var applicationDocumentsDirectory: NSURL = {
    // The directory the application uses to store the Core Data store file. This code uses a directory named "com.wt9t.BaseballsInsightVersionBeta" in the application's documents Application Support directory.
    let urls = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask)
    return urls[urls.count-1]
}()

lazy var managedObjectModel: NSManagedObjectModel = {
    // The managed object model for the application. This property is not optional. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
    let modelURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("BaseballsInsightVersionBeta", withExtension: "momd")!
    return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: modelURL)!
}()

lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = {
    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and return a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    // Create the coordinator and store
    var coordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator? = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("BaseballsInsightVersionBeta.sqlite")
    var error: NSError? = nil
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
    let mOptions = [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true,
        NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true]
    do {
        try coordinator!.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: nil)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.localizedDescription)

    }

    return coordinator
}()

lazy var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext? = {
    // Returns the managed object context for the application (which is already bound to the persistent store coordinator for the application.) This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the context to fail.
    let coordinator = self.persistentStoreCoordinator
    if coordinator == nil {
        return nil
    }
    var managedObjectContext = NSManagedObjectContext(concurrencyType: NSManagedObjectContextConcurrencyType.MainQueueConcurrencyType)
    managedObjectContext.persistentStoreCoordinator = coordinator
    return managedObjectContext
}()

// MARK: - Core Data Saving support

func saveContext () {
    if managedObjectContext!.hasChanges {
        do {
            try managedObjectContext!.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nserror = error as NSError
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            abort()
        }
    }
}

}
```

Also i am including my initial view controller called MainVC

```
import UIKit
import CoreData
import Foundation
import SystemConfiguration

class MainVC: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var chartCountTextView: UITextView!
let cdao = CoreDataRequests()

var chartsCompleted:Array<String> = []

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("Viewdidload finished")
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGrayColor()

    let count = cdao.getChartCountInQueue()

    if(count != 0)
    {

        chartCountTextView.text = "\(count) charts have yet to be uploaded, click Chart Queue to start the process"
    }
    else
    {
        chartCountTextView.text = ""
    }

    chartCountTextView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    let email = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("userEmail")
    let password = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().stringForKey("userPassword")

    if(email == nil || password == nil)
    {
        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("login", sender: self)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Please ensure Info.plist contains the main storyboard file name, although updating should not change it, but just a random thought.

Comment: my Info.plist doesn't contain the main.storyboard file name exactly but has values such as $(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER) in the bundle identifier key and $(PRODUCT_NAME) in the Bundle Name key. Is this what your talking about?